# html css style not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place some text inside an image, but the text div is not coming on top of the image, rather it is hidden and invisible right below the image. thanks in advance!

Here is a link to jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/XrXZj/1/

have the following in my css file:

```
.spotlight {
     color:#FFFFFF;
     display:table;
     height:120px;
     margin-bottom:15px;
     margin-left:0px;
     overflow:hidden;
     padding:0 50px;
     position:relative;
     width:840px;
}

.spotlight .wrapper {
     position:absolute;
}

.spotlight .middle {
      display:table-cell;
      height:50px;
      vertical-align:middle;
 }

.spotlight .spotlight-copy {
     font-size:15px;
     line-height:25px;
     width:500px;
}
```

and here is the content of html file:

```
 <div class="spotlight">
 <img src="<spring:url value="/assets/img/banner-natural-hazard-risk.jpg"/>"                 border="0" />
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="spotlight-copy">
                <spring:message code="content.location.title" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: have a look at `position:absolute` and `zindex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.spotlight .wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This perfectly works. Though the text is not centered or middle of the image. "spotlight .middle" - this style is not working.

Comment: I cannot see your image. Try use this: `.spotlight .middle {
   display:table-cell;
   height:120px; /* your height */
   width:500px; /* your width */
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align: center;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I put there a solution http://jsfiddle.net/NPh76/

HTML is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="spotlight">
        <img src="http://www.springsource.org/files/header/logo-spring-103x60.png"                 border="0" />
        <div class="spotlight-copy">
            message in spotlight copy
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

notice about `HTML`:

- `<IMG>` is into `.middle` to be at same level as `.spotlight-copy`

CSS is:

```
.spotlight {
 color:#FFFFFF;
 display:table;
 height:120px;
 margin-bottom:15px;
 margin-left:0px;
 overflow:hidden;
 padding:0 50px;
position:absolute;
 width:840px;
}

.spotlight .wrapper {
 position:absolute;
}

.spotlight .middle {
 display:table-cell;
 height:50px;
 vertical-align:middle;
}

.spotlight .spotlight-copy {
 position:absolute;
 top: 0px;
 font-size:15px;
 line-height:25px;
 width:500px;
 color:#FF0000;
}
```

notice about `CSS`

- `position:absolute;` in `.spotlight-copy`
- `top: 0px;` for position
- `color:#FF0000;` to see something ;)